# How to take payload of an API as an argument in ruby function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, binding.pry

I have done rails c on my console of rubymine.

I want to execute a function in rails console.

the function is

```
funtion_one(Api_payload , some_integer_Value)
```

API_payload is : -

```
{
"data" : [
    {
        "from" : "today",
          "to" : "next_day"
    }
],
  "some_ids" : [
    9808
]
}
```

so basically how do i write it in rails console ..?

```
pry(main)>  function_one({ "date_ranges" : [ { "from" : "today", "to" : "next_day" } ], "some_ids" : [ 9808 ] } , 25)
```

after writing above command , error comes , which is **SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the incoming payload, since it isn't ruby hash.

```rb
# Notice the ' and beginning and end, it needs to be a string

payload = '{
  "data" : [
      {
        "from" : "today",
        "to" : "next_day"
      }
    ],
   "some_ids" : [9808]
  }'

usable_payload = JSON.parse(payload)

# then call your method
method_one(usable_payload, 25)
```